# How to use phpunit --testsuite option?

Tags: php, phpunit

How do I use the phpunit --testsuite command?

For example, I have a testfile:

```
test/xxx/RegistrationConfirmedListenerTest.php
```

If I run phpunit, then it will run the tests in RegistrationConfirmedListenerTest.php, but it also runs all other tests in my tests folder.

I have tried using this the --testsuite option like this:

```
phpunit --testsuite RegistrationConfirmedListenerTest
```

However, nothing runs.

```
PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.



Time: 46 ms, Memory: 4.00Mb

No tests executed!
```

I have read the docs here but there aren't any examples to help:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `phpunit.xml` and define your testsuites there.

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="youttestsuitename1">
        <file>./path/to/folder/</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="youttestsuitename1">
        <file>./path/to/folder2/</file>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

More info to [official documentations](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html)